# Duplicate batch is not working as the original one

Tags: batch

I have created a chain of batch classes (5 batch classes calling each other) and everything working as expected. After this is deployed in production, to do a real time testing and debugging for future enhancements, I replicated the entire batch process and the custom objects involved in the original batch. Lets say the original batch is called abc and it insert/update/delete records in a custom objects called xyz and to do these dmls, standard objects like orderproduct, workorder, etc are involved.

To duplicate the process, I created another object called xyz-test, replicated all the batches, and suffixed -testing to their names (abc-testing). Also, I made sure that instead of the original object, the test object is referred in this batch chain.

I scheduled both the batches at the same time. But both are returning different results. The test batch is not working as the original batch. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: _test batch is not working as the original batch_ what do you mean by not working! Can you be more specific?

Comment: I meant its not working as the original one. I updated the title.

Comment: We're going to need more information to go on. You can't just say "it's different" or "it's not working." That could mean almost anything. The more information you give us, the better we can help you. Describe how it's different. What are the expected results, versus what did you see? You might even want to actually share your code, it may be that we can spot the differences.

Comment: Its a total of 10 classes and I am not sure if I can post here all the 10 classes. Here are the differences :

Comment: Here are the differences :  The batch is suppose to insert records on the abc object based on various criteria from order product. The original process  returns 98k records, while the duplicate other returns 94K. Post this, the other batches, based on many criteria, are suppose to stamp these abc and abc-test records. Even stamping is not in sync AND there is no difference in the logic.

Comment: My question is: Is there anything in Salesforce when one particular record is used in one query in one batch, its locked  to be used in another query? I don't think anything like is there....but just not able to figure out as what can be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. Records were getting locked by the first batch and as a result, the other batch was not considering those records.

Comment: How you handeled it? Might worth adding to this answer

Comment: I scheduled both the processes with a gap of 1 hour.